Istio GKE API access
I have a setup of Istio and GKE configuration. In the istio authorization file I have added rule such that post call to an api is allowed only from specific ip address. The api is designed by me and we are able to make post call successfully to the api using postman after whitelisting the ip address. Now, we want Esendex services (sms service) to use this api. We have added the API endpoint as webhook in Esendex. We have whitelisted the IP address CIDR and SMS download IP address provided by Esendex in our system via Istio authorization file. We have also allowed port 25 (email server for esendex), port 80 and port 443. Still Esendex is unable to use the api and no response is coming in our logs.
Below is the istio authorization yaml file:
apiVersion: "security.istio.io/v1beta1"
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: {{ include "helpers.name" . }}-authz-allow-token
  namespace: {{ include "helpers.namespace" . }}
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "helpers.name" . }}
  rules:
    - from:
      - source:
          principals:
            {{- range .Values.authorization.validSourcePrincipals }}
              - {{ . | quote }}
            {{- end }}
      when:
      - key: request.auth.claims[iss]
        values:
          {{- range .Values.authorization.validIssuers }}
            - {{ . | quote }}
          {{- end }}
---

apiVersion: "security.istio.io/v1beta1"
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: {{ include "helpers.name" . }}-authz-allow-anonymous
  namespace: {{ include "helpers.namespace" . }}
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "helpers.name" . }}
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
      from:
      - source: 
          remoteIpBlocks: [{{- range .Values.esendexIps }} {{ . }}, {{- end}}]
      to:
      - operation:
          methods: ["GET","POST"]
          paths: ["/api*"]

We are using Octopus for deployment to Kubernetes cluster and the above value is passed via variable in Octopus to the cluster. Could you please suggest what more needs to be done
